# Adding star rating to Django comments

Tags: django, frameworks, comments, rating

I'd like to modify the existing Django comments framework to include star ratings.  The Django site has good documentation on modifying the comments framework [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/custom/), but I still have a few questions.

1. Unfortunately I don't have much experience modifying forms. If I wanted to incorporate the [jQuery star rating plugin](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/) into my form how would I go about doing that?
2. When creating my custom comment model I assume a IntegerField or a FloatField would be best to store the rating?
3. Should I write a [validator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/) to verify that the rating is between 0-5 or whatever the range ends up being, or will I not have to worry about that because the star ratings will only go 0-5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can set HTML attributes into your inputs (class="star") as described here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs
2. Probably a IntegerField, keep it simple.
3. No, a user could hack the javascript and submit any value. Never trust user input ! Write your own validator :)